# How do I log or view the cost used in training a TensorFlow neural network with dropout?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

How do I see the accuracy and cost for the dropouts actually used in training a [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#dropout) neural network with [dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#dropout)?

As expected, each time I run a [summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter), e.g. with

```
train_writer.add_summary(sess.run(merged, feed_dict=foo), step)
```

or

```
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=foo))
```

if the network includes dropout, and `foo` feeds a “keep probability” other than 1.0, I will get different values, so that, for example, I get a different loss or accuracy each time — e.g., three immediately successive computations of accuracy with

```
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=foo))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=foo))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=foo))
```

might give something like

```
75.808
75.646
75.770
```

Though these are roughly the same, they are not exactly the same, presumably because each time I evaluate, the network drops out different nodes. A consequence of this must be that I don’t ever see the cost actually encountered in training.

How do I log or view the cost (or other summary values computed using the network) actually used in training a TensorFlow neural network with dropout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And where is the problem? You **should** get three different values if you call three times a stochastic network. When you are logging your losses from network you are logging the ones that are actually used during training. Basically you can just read out value from your computed graph, like:

```
for i in range(100):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y))
    _, loss_val = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy],
                           feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    print 'loss = ' + loss_val
```

which will print the loss which was computed **during training step** (it will not compute it twice, thus the dropout output mask will not be resampled).

If instead you want to see "what would be the accuracy on train set if I stop learning now" you need an **eval graph** https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#evaluate-the-model , which will tell your network, that it is time to change dropout units from stochastic, to scaling/averaging results.

Comment: The "problem" is not that I get three (or however many) different values (that's expected), it's about how to access the one encountered during training.

Comment: To make sure I have the critical point about how to accomplish that access: is it the case than anything provided to a single call to `run` will only be evaluated *once* no matter how many times it is encountered in the evaluation process, so that if I pass `[op1, op2, op3]` and, say, `op1` itself evaluates `op2` which in turn evaluates `op3`, the values I'll see for the latter two will be the same as those used in computing `op1`?

Comment: If that's right, the other critical part of the question is: how do I get that value (`loss_val` in your example) into the log (e.g., with `SummaryWriter`)?

Comment: Yes, if you pass multiple things to run, the underlying graph will be evaluated only once. This is the whole deal with TF - it analyzes your execution graph, and only exectues required nodes, never executing the same one twice.

Comment: And again - during training there is no "accuracy" - your network is trained with surrogate loss (like log loss) and this is the value actually enountered during training (and it is completely independent on using dropout or not - this just works). You can instead ask (as in the second part of answer) "what would happen if I stop trianing now and try to evaluate training set in terms of accuracy" - which is described in details in do_eval documentation under link provided

Comment: Cool. And is there some simple idiom I'm missing for putting `loss_val`, now that I see how to get it, in the log — e.g., with `add_summary` — that I'm missing.

Comment: Can "what would happen if I stop trianing now and try to evaluate training set in terms of accuracy" be answered simply by running with the training data and `keep_prob == 1.0`, e.g., with `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y, keep_prob: 1.0})`?