# How do I determine the training "accuracy" for a TensorFlow network with dropout?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102454/656912) that "accuracy" isn't what measured against the training set for a neural network during training, but I'd like to know, essentially

> what would happen if I stop trianing now and try to evaluate training set in terms of accuracy

at various points during training of a TensorFlow network being trained with dropout.

Can this question be answered simply by running with the training data and `keep_prob == 1.0`, that is with something like

```
sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

Comment: I think what you have is correct. However, why you want to measure the training accuracy? Do you want to see if the model overfits?

Comment: @SungKim: To have something to directly compare with the validation/test set accuracies as training progresses, esp. rates of change.

Comment: Then, your code looks good.

Comment: @SungKim: I'll accept that as an answer.